# Avoiding memory leaks in jni code

Tags: java, c++

I'm writing a jni code in which i have to frequently convert std::string to jstring and vice versa, for which i'm using following functions

```
//std::string to jstring

const char *cons_ref = ANY_STD_STRING.c_str();

jstring jref = env->NewStringUTF(cons_ref);

//jstring to std::string

const char *cons_ref = env->GetStringUTFChars(ANY_JSTRING, 0);

std::string ANY_STD_STRING = cons_ref
```

But this is leading to creation of a lot of const char* which are read only and cannot be deleted, thus causing memory leaks.

Is there a better technique to do these conversions to avoid memory leaks. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What makes you think that code is causing memory leaks?

Comment: Do you know what a const char* is?

Comment: pointer to a const string

Comment: i guess u mean that i can create as many const char* as i want, and there is no need of releasing of deleting them.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious when i run my code for smaller input string it works fine, but when i test my code of larger string inputs it shows this error  JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512) and Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)

Comment: I would run valgrind with your JNI shared library to validate that you have a memory leak.  That will most likely answer your question.  Build with symbols so you can also print out line numbers.

Comment: Did you try `env->DeleteLocalRef(jref)`?

Comment: Is there any way to release memory used by "env->CallStaticObjectMethod()"

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're dealing with something that returns a pointer, you should look at the documentation for that function. Ideally it should tell you whether or not you're responsible for deallocating/releasing that memory. And if so it should tell you how.

I don't know JNI, but with a little googling I found http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

On that page it says:

> const char * GetStringUTFChars(JNIEnv *env, jstring string, jboolean
>   *isCopy);
>
> Returns a pointer to an array of bytes representing the string in
>   modified UTF-8 encoding. This array is valid until it is released by
>   ReleaseStringUTFChars().

So it sounds like you should be doing something like:

```
//jstring to std::string

const char *cons_ref = env->GetStringUTFChars(ANY_JSTRING, 0);

std::string ANY_STD_STRING = cons_ref;

env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(ANY_JSTRING, cons_ref);
```

Comment: but what should be done in //std::string to jstring , in that the const char* is still formed and not released

Comment: The c_str() method of std::string doesn't give ownership of the memory to the caller. The object is still responsible for it. So there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: I'm also using this function in a loop                                                             "a = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(integerClass, value, sub, radix);" .I'm also deleting "a" outside loop with this "env->DeleteLocalRef(a);". But it looks that multiple objects are created in this loop and are never free